# How we add new item dynamically when when i am at the last position

Tags: windows-phone-7

how to dynamically add item in list box When i vertically scroll down .i want to add ten items that i add at the end of my list box .but i do not have any idea about this, so please give any idea ,if you have and also give me a link for this if you have . 
It Just Like Pull up to refresh.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the solution as listed here:

[WP7 – How To Extend ListBox When Reaching Last Item](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/archive/2011/04/06/wp7-how-to-extend-listbox-when-reaching-last-item.aspx)